# How should I handle private key when sending transactions?

Tags: transactions, account, wallet, security

How can I send a transaction from my backend without leaving the private key in the code?

I want only me to be able to do this transaction but if I leave the private key in the code, it is easily exposable.

The transaction has to be sent somehow but not sure how to do it from the backend without having access to my wallet there.

Comment: My initial thought was to put the private key in the system env var and pull it from there (instead of saving it to .env) but is there another way?

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Not sure yet - didn't deploy anywhere but will run it on a VPS - Node.js

Comment: You will need to create a keypair for signing transactions and store it on the VPS. It could be put there manually or fetched from a vault automatically. The question is a bit too broad for me to be more specific.

Comment: So i want to fire transactions from my backend, and for this i need a wallet, perhaps the best option is to save it as an environment variable on the VPS, so I don't have to include it in the backend code.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, using an env file is typically best for this.

- Don't check in your `.env` file
- Ensure your `.gitignore` includes `.env` so you don't accidentally check in your code
- Load the env file from your client app. Eg [loading an env file in node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs):

```
node --env-file=.env app.js
```

You can then access the private key from your environment.

There are also apps called "secrets managers" you can use to fill the environment with your secrets instead, and ensure the secrets are changable but that their values are not revealed.